# Spring + Hibernate: Initializing database with JUnit doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, junit

I have simple database with one Vehicle table (using MySQL):

```
create table vehicle (
    vehicle_no varchar(10) not null,
    color varchar(10),
    wheel int,
    seat int,
    primary key (vehicle_no)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

In Java, I have DAO object that should query for all vehicles (other methods of DAO are ommited). This DAO should join existing transaction or create new if required:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public class HibernateVehicleDao implements VehicleDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
        return currentSession().createQuery("from Vehicle").list();
    }
}
```

Now, I've written JUnit test (JUnit4) for DAO. Before running test method, it should insert 10 vehicles to database and after running it should delete all vehicles. I've **separately tested** this behaviour with Spring's JDBC and everything works properly, so there shouldn't be problem.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/sk/xorty/dataaccess/dataaccess-beans.xml")
public class HibernateVehicleDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private static final int COUNT = 10;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hibernateVehicleDao")
    private VehicleDao dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String insert = 
                "INSERT INTO VEHICLE (VEHICLE_NO, COLOR, WHEEL, SEAT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        List<Object[]> argsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            argsList.add(VehicleUtil.nextVehicleArgs());
        }
        simpleJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insert, argsList);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        simpleJdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM VEHICLE", (Object[]) null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
        assertEquals (COUNT, dao.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

Everything loads, so I suspect configuration is correct and dependencies were properly injected.

**Problem is**, that test fails because database is empty (no vehicles). When I insert them manually, they are never deleted on the other hand.

Please try to **pay attention to using transactional annotations**, I am fairly new to this and I think that I might have done mistake somewhere there.

Here's my bean configuration file if that might be any help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- shared data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" 
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/vehicles" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JDBC transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses" >
            <list>
                <value>sk.xorty.dataaccess.Vehicle</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateVehicleDao" class="sk.xorty.dataaccess.HibernateVehicleDao" />

</beans>
```

**EDIT: Requested Vehicle entity code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="VEHICLE_NO", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String vehicleNo;
    private String color;
    private int wheel;
    private int seat;

    public Vehicle() {}

    public Vehicle(String vehicleNo, String color, int wheel, int seat) {
        this.vehicleNo = vehicleNo;
        this.color = color;
        this.wheel = wheel;
        this.seat = seat;
    }

    public String getVehicleNo() {
        return vehicleNo;
    }

    public void setVehicleNo(String vehicleNo) {
        this.vehicleNo = vehicleNo;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getWheel() {
        return wheel;
    }

    public void setWheel(int wheel) {
        this.wheel = wheel;
    }

    public int getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public void setSeat(int seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle [vehicleNo=" + vehicleNo + ", color=" + color
                + ", wheel=" + wheel + ", seat=" + seat + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + seat;
        result = prime * result
                + ((vehicleNo == null) ? 0 : vehicleNo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + wheel;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Vehicle other = (Vehicle) obj;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
            return false;
        if (seat != other.seat)
            return false;
        if (vehicleNo == null) {
            if (other.vehicleNo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!vehicleNo.equals(other.vehicleNo))
            return false;
        if (wheel != other.wheel)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the Vehicle entity?

Comment: Where do you instantiate simpleJdbcTemplate?

Comment: It's inherited from AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and it's created when Spring is autowiring dataSource (I have one in beans.xml) to this parent class.

Comment: If your defining the JDBC template in beans.xml i think you may need to import that configuration file in your current configuration file.

Comment: Nope, I am not defining JDBC template at all and I don't need to, because it's automatically created as long as dataSource exists. I checked source code of AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests class.

Comment: just read the documentation on that and it suggests flushing the session.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if this matters but the casing in the following method is incorrect:

```
@Override
public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
    return currentSession().createQuery("from Vehicle").list();
}
```

The table name starts with a lowercase v in "vehicle" while this method uses an uppercase "V".

Another interesting thing I read from the documentation:

> simpleJdbcTemplate: useful for querying to confirm state. For example,
>   you might query before and after testing application code that creates
>   an object and persists it using an ORM tool, to verify that the data
>   appears in the database. (Spring will ensure that the query runs in
>   the scope of the same transaction.) You will need to tell your ORM
>   tool to 'flush' its changes for this to work correctly, for example
>   using the flush() method on Hibernate's Session interface.

Try flushing the session before executing your query.

Comment: HQL uses names of entities not SQL tables afaik. Just for the sake of clarity I tried it with lowercase letter and result was org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Comment: flushing in hibernate dao didn't help either :(